# Is there a way to pass the input fields in redux form to another component?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I want to pass this input value to another component state. To be clear I want the value of this redux form input to pass it to the state of the another component. Is there anyway to achieve it?

```
renderTextField(field){
            return(
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>{field.label}</label>
                    <input
                        className="form-control"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Name"
                        {...field.input}
                        required
                    />
                </div>
            )
        }

    render(){
            const {handleSubmit}=this.props;
            return(
              <form style={newrow} onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
                  <Field
                      label={"Student Name"}
                      name="name"
                      component={this.renderTextField}
                  />
                  <Field
                      label={"Average Grade"}
                      name="avgGrade"
                      component={this.renderTextField}
                  />
                  <Field
                      label={"Curriculum / Occupation"}
                      name="occupation"
                      component={this.renderTextField}
                  />
                  <button className="btn btn-primary btn-right">Create</button>
              </form>
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`redux-form` values are stored in the redux state so they are accessible as any other redux values. They are under `form.yourFormName.values.yourInputName` (assuming you called your redux-form reducer `form`)

Comment: Yea my formreducer name is form but it is not workig it is saying form is not defined.. Sorry pretty noob at this.

Comment: Check with redux devtools if you have indeed a reducer called form and what are its values. Then please share more info on *who* is saying that the form it is not defined. With limited info it is hard to debug

Comment: Yeah k I'll check